# Is it common to use 'terminus a quo' in academic writing?

Tags: latin, academic-writing

I'm writing an academic paper and I want to replace the word 'starting point' with 'terminus a quo'. I'm not sure if this Latin word is commonly used. I'm trying to make my language more interesting but I don't want to use a word most people don't know. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Good lord, no! !

Comment: Your only answerer shows that they’d never heard of it and could only find one use, which was in a 17th century manuscript. As you say, you don’t want to use a term that nobody knows - not only because they won’t understand, but more importantly you presumably have something useful to say and you’ll be detracting from this.

Comment: You may use _terminus a quo_ to mean 'place where it came from', **provided** you also use _terminus ad quem_ to mean 'place where it went to'. Otherwise, the Latin won't be paired up and the sentence will break.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Questions where research has proved fruitless may be closed if no _signs_ of research are provided.

Comment: There is no such thing as **the** style of writing academic papers; the styles are discipline specific. If you are writing an academic paper, you have presumably read many academic papers in the same discipline. If you have, in your studies, seen that term (or similar terms) used by reputable scholars **in your field**, then it is OK to use it in your paper; if not, not. Any answer that may be given here by people who don't work in the same field is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for the comment:)

Comment: I dunno--I've heard it used in grad school classes, and I'm considering putting it into my thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only instance I could find of this after searching in various corpora was in Early English Books Online:

> 't is such a choosing of error as is accompanied with a rejecting of
> truth: a Hereticke puts light for darknesse, and darknes or light;
> good fo evill, and evill for good, he chooseth eror as truth, and
> refseth truth as error, they that give heed to seducing pirits and
> doctrines of devils, do also depart from the faith, 1 tim: 4: 1:
> resist the, 2 tim 3: 8, and turne away their ears from the truth, 2
> tim: 4: 4: their course hath a **teminus a quo** als well as ad quem:
> 4't is an error professed and maintained, and which y that means
> becomes a scandal and snare to others: for although there may be
> Heresie (as well as other kinds of sinurking and hid in the thoughts,
> yet that belongs to gods judgement only, not to mans: the heresies
> which are spoken of (A treatise of miscellany questions wherein many usefull questions and cases of conscience are discussed and resolved, 1649; Gillespie, George, 1613-1648. | Gillespie, Patrick, 1617-1675)

So if you'd like to add that 17th century flair to your writing, crack on!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't search "teminus a quo" without the R? With the R it's slightly more common although the basic guidance still applies.

Comment: @StuartF Ha, I did misspell it in the searches. It's actually more common than I'd made it out to be. Edit incoming. Thanks for pointing that out!